# Python- os.chdir takes an open excel file instance into account while execution

Tags: python, excel, pandas, python-3.7, glob

I have some excel files in a folder. I use the below code to read those excel files and get them into a list so that I can pass that list into a loop to get particular data from all those files.

My problem is - If I open a excel file from that folder and run the script.The opened excel file instance is created in the folder and the script now takes that temporary instance as an .xlsx file and returms it in the list and passes it to the loop where it eventually fails as -"No such directory" I found a way of avoiding the failure by adding in a "-1" from lenght of list to loop.But this isnt effective.

Please suggest any alternatives for os.chdir

```
import pandas as pd
import glob
import os

os.chdir(r'\\servername/Files_to_Read')
files = [i for i in glob.glob('*.{}'.format('xlsx'))]
print(files)

s = 0
while(len(files) > s):
    print(files[s])
    df_getvalues = pd.read_excel(files[s], sheet_name="LISTS", header=None)
    dfindx = (df_getvalues.index)
    print("This is the index of the file - " +str(dfindx))
    print(df_getvalues.iloc[dfindx,0])
    s = s + 1
```

error:-

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\Users\$name_of_file.xlsx'

The error states that it is searching for the file in C drive but actual folder of excel files is on H drive.

Note - Im using Windows 10, Excel 2016 , python 3.7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue seems to be very intermittent and this never occurred again after I did a reboot and I also had some issues with my VM migration and my profile has been configured manually so I dont know what among the various reasons helped me to get out of this issue.

Also, I am not using OS.Chdir now . I am using path and list directory this time as I saw somewhere that chdir is not so recommended.

```
list_dirctry_content = os.listdir(src)

for xlfile in list_dirctry_content:
    str_name_file = os.path.join(src, xlfile)
    if(str_name_file.endswith('.xlsx')):
        final_driving_list.append(str_name_file.strip(src))
```